# Recursively download website on Windows preserving Unicode filenames

Tags: windows, download, encoding, unicode, filenames

Normally I use [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget) to grab websites recursively.

But I want to fetch some websites with lots of Unicode URLs for various languages and I'd like to keep the Unicode in the filenames. ([Here's an example.](https://incubator.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wp/nod))

wget has commandline switches `--local-encoding` and `--remote-encoding` but they don't seem to support Windows' native filesystem encoding, UTF-16. I think this is because wget is designed for *nix which never has UTF-16 as a system encoding for filenames and Windows ports of wget are not official.

How can I do this under Windows and keep the files using correct Unicode?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I removed the shopping part of the question. It should now be as acceptable as other questions here such as http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Comment: Much better. Vote to close removed ;)

Comment: Have you tried [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fwget%2Fwget-1.17.1-1&grep=wget)'s `wget`?

Comment: I might try that. I'm not sure if this netbook's puny internal drive has enough space left to install cygwin. I doubt I'd use it much for other stuff these days.

Comment: The minimum install is only 1.4 GB (see [What is the minimal packages list for Cygwin?](http://superuser.com/q/879627)). Adding `wget` won't add very much to that.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Should we close this old one? http://superuser.com/questions/67604/free-mac-os-x-application-for-downloading-an-entire-website

Comment: Yes. I've voted to close.