# Cygwin... achieve a more reasonable installation?

Tags: bash, git, cygwin, bloatware

I had seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/879627/what-is-the-minimal-packages-list-for-cygwin) from 2015 about a "minimal" Cygwin installation.

My main use for Cygwin is (currently at least) essentially git and a few very standard bash commands. I didn't know how I might restrict the installation to just those requirements so I just accepted the default "core" installation.

Whereas in that 2015 post there is talk of the "minmal"/"core" installation being 100 MB I just used TreeSize to have a look at the installation I've just done: it's taking up 10.3 GB!

I'm sorry but for my requirements, and as a "core" installation, this is crazy... does anyone know how to de-bloat this?

Comment: If you just select the packages you actually need any dependencies will be figured out and installed as well. Having said I don't know what the minimal installation is these days. However, I have a lot more than the minimum installed and my installation is only 205 MB ...

Comment: Thanks... if you have a moment could you say whether you're using the 32-bit version? I'm using the 64-bit. A quick look at the TreeSize results shows that the top "culprits" are under usr/ : x86_64-w64-mingw32, i686-w64-mingw32 and "share" : these 3 dirs take up nearly 2 GB each...

Comment: I'm using the 64 bit version. Did you install source code? My directories are a lot smaller `x86_64-w64-mingw32` is 12.1 MB for example.

Comment: Thanks, just reinstalled... installation taking up 100 MB! Have no idea what I did wrong the first time round, it's not like there are that many options...

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) - you should turn your comment into an answer. :)

Comment: Another option is also to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux, although it's on 64-bit only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried again... perfectly respectable 100 MB.  Have no idea what I did wrong first time!